# Running "git filter-branch" from bash shell

Tags: bash, git

I can't seem to get the "git filter-branch" to work inside bash:

```
  fix_commit_date() { 
   git filter-branch --env-filter \
     'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = "${1}" ]
      then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="${2}"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="${2}"
      fi' -f
   }
```

This is the error message I get:

```
fix_commit_date b62178fd4d40e1e52a7bfef64ff2f269c3aff7f8 "Mon Aug 12 13:03:00 2019"
Rewrite b62178fd4d40e1e52a7bfef64ff2f269c3aff7f8 (8/8) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    
WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
```

It works fine in bash if I just type it out and not use fix_commit_date.  Any ideas how I can get the fix_commit_date bash command to work?  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I just type it out*"? What's the actual command?

Comment: git filter-branch --env-filter \
    'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = b62178fd4d40e1e52a7bfef64ff2f269c3aff7f8 ]
     then
         export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Mon Aug 12 13:03:00 2019"
         export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon Aug 12 13:03:00 2019"
     fi' -f

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your shell function uses inappropriate quoting.

Try prefixing `git filter-branch` with `echo`:

```
echo git filter-branch --env-filter \
  'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = b62178fd4d40e1e52a7bfef64ff2f269c3aff7f8 ]
  then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="Mon Aug 12 13:03:00 2019"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon Aug 12 13:03:00 2019"
  fi' -
```

Observe the output.  What do you see for the test for the commit hash ID?

Then try your shell function as written, again inserting `echo` in front of `git`:

```
fix_commit_date() { 
   echo git filter-branch --env-filter \
     'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = "${1}" ]
      then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="${2}"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="${2}"
      fi' -f
}

fix_commit_date b62178fd4d40e1e52a7bfef64ff2f269c3aff7f8 "Mon Aug 12 13:03:00 2019"
```

What output do you see?

The trick here is to expand the arguments `$1` and `$2`, yet still provide the entire expression as a single word to the command.  There are numerous ways to do this; here's one:

```
fix_commit_date() { 
   git filter-branch --env-filter \
     'if [ $GIT_COMMIT = "'"${1}"'" ]
      then
        export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="'"${2}"'"
        export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="'"${2}"'"
      fi' -f
}
```

Try this variant with the `echo` inserted first.

---

Incidentally, one of my favorite tricks for encoding this sort of thing in a more readable manner is to set a shell variable to contain a double quote:

```
DQ='"'
echo "John told me to say ${DQ}hello${DQ}"
```

Each of the shell-expanded metacharacters can be put in a variable:

```
DOL='$'
BQ='`'
SQ="'"  # not technically needed
```

Otherwise "invisible" characters can be set up as well:

```
TAB=$'\t'
NL=$'\n'
```

Now you can write things like:

```
echo "This has some ${DOL}weird ${BQ}ch${TAB}ara${NL}cters in it, doesn't it?"
```

Comment: It works.  Thanks so much for the echo debugging tip!